# Substituting the limit to the sum bound

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am wondering if I can write the following? Or if there is any conditions that make it hold?

$\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim \sum_{r=1}^\infty f(n,r)=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}\lim \sum_{r=1}^n f(n,r)$

Comment: They're the same.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, these are not the same:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^nf(n,r)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n,1)+\cdots+f(n,n))$$
while
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{r=1}^\infty f(n,r)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{r\to\infty}(f(n,1)+\cdots+f(n,r)).$$

Comment: Are there any conditions under which they are equal?

Comment: Uniformly with respect to n?

Comment: What is the domain of $f(n,r)$?

Comment: $\{1,2,\cdots\}\times\{1,2,\cdots\}$

Comment: Suppose $\sum_{r=1}f(n,r)=F(n)$.  The condition you need is that for every $\epsilon>0$  there must be an $R\in\Bbb N_+$ such that $r>R\implies |\sum_{k=1}^f(n,k)-F(n)|<\epsilon$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_+$.